# Implementing Convolution in Frequency Domain?

Tags: image-processing, fft, fourier-transform, convolution, fast-convolution

Suppose, we have a bitmap image represented as a 2D integer array,
 `int [,] image2D;` whose FFT is `Complex[,] fftImage2D;`

Suppose, we have an kernel represented as a 2D integer array,
 `int [,] kernel2D;` whose FFT is `Complex[,] fftKernel2D;`

We know that, the convolution (in spatial domain) of `image2D` and `kernel2D` would be,

```
int Rows = image2D.GetLength(0);
int Cols = image2D.GetLength(1);

for(int i=0 ; i<Rows ; i++)
{
    for(int j=0 ; j<Cols ; j++)
    {
        //sweep the kernel2D across image2D
        //...........................
    }
}
```

We also know that, convolution in frequency domain would be, multiplication between `fftImage2D` and `fftKernel2D`.

**How can I do this multiplication?**

How can I multiply two `Complex [,]` type 2D arrays of different dimensions? I have understood the theory. My problem is practical implementation. As I described in the question,

1. Are DFT of the image and DFT of the kernel going to be of different sizes? I guess so. So, how can I multiply them element by element?
2. In my code, each of the DFTs are represented by 2D Complex numbers. Should, I multiply them according to complex-number's multiplication rule? Probably yes. But, only when their dimensions are same. Right?

Answer (score 3):

IDFT the smaller or both of the DFTs if needed.  Zero pad one or both of the kernel and image to make them the same dimension and size.  Re-DFT as needed, and now you can complex multiply the 2 DFT arrays element-by-element because they will now be the same size.

Comment: But, if I zero-pad the smaller one (in most cases, the kernel), should I keep the kernel at the center and surround them with zeros, or should I shift the kernel in one of the corners?

Comment: Depends on how you want the result offset.  I typically zero-pad both up to a factorable-into-small-primes size that is equal or greater than N+M-1, with the originals centered in the zero padding, or fftshift one or both.

Comment: What is the common/standard/general procedure?